# Использование прокси для доступа к бэку(модификация URL)

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, прокси

Необходимо настроить nginx.

Конфиг:

```
        location /test1212 {
                rewrite ^/test1212(/.*)$ $1 break;
        }
```

Проблема в том, что в url не вырезается `/test1212`.

Как сделать это вырезание на nginx?

Comment: А откуда он должен вырезаться? Может вам нужен редирект?

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite ^/test1212(/.*)$ $1 break;`

Тут Вы говорите серверу взять первый(`$1`) элемент пути , он и берет  `/test1212`. Просто измените на `$2`.

`rewrite ^/test1212(/.*)$ $2 break;`

Comment: `$1` это не первый элемент, а первая группа.

Comment: @AlexeyTen https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
`The $1 and $2 variables capture the path elements that aren't changing`

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете эту фразу. Там имеется в виду что в `$1` и `$2` попадут части которые должны остаться неизменными.

Comment: @AlexeyTen проясните?

Comment: Регулярки почти везде одинаковые. Вот дока по питону, https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub. Тут тоже самое только в питоне используется `\1` вместо `$1`.